# Why do the same BP model get different results on the same test set?

Tags: neural-network, classification, backpropagation

In a classification task, I trained a BP network with the same training set several times and evaluated it with the same test set. However, the resulting classification accuracy showed two extremes, either close to 0 or close to 100%. It would be of great help if anyone could explain this problem.

I have tested about five times.

Comment: Possibly random weight initialization, but impossible to say with certainty since you did not include any code.